# Como seriam os métodos de @DELETE de uma api RESTfull java?

Tags: java, http, restful, back-end, delete

Estou usando o `FullEntityRepository` da `deltaspike`, o `Response` tem que ser um status `204` caso dê certo, e status `400` caso não dê. Alguma dica?
Camada service:

```
@Transactional
public void deletar(Integer id){
  MotivoConcessao motivoConcessaoParaDeletar = repositorio.findBy(id);
  repositorio.remove(motivoConcessaoParaDeletar);
}

Camada resource:
@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public Response deletar(@PathParam("id") @Min(value = 1, message = "{recursomotivoconcessao.id.min}") Integer id) {
  return Response.status(204).entity(servico.deletar(id)).build();
}
```

Comment: A variável `repositorio` é de qual classe?

Comment: E do FullEntityRepository cara, da deltaspike. Pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.7.1/org/apache/deltaspike/data/api/EntityPersistenceRepository.html#remove-E-) do DeltaSpike, o método `remove` evoca o método `remove` da classe `EntityManager`. Como o método da última lança uma `IllegalArgumentException` caso falhe, você poderia tentar capturar essa exceção e, caso ela ocorra, enviar a resposta com o status desejado. Exemplo:

```
@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public Response deletar(@PathParam("id") 
                        @Min(value = 1, message = "{ recursomotivoconcessao.id.min}") 
                        Integer id) {
    try {
        servico.deletar(id);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         return Response.status(409).build();
    }
    return Response.status(204).build();
}
```